# Suddenly have oil leaks in lots of different places

Tags: pontiac, oil-leak, solstice, valve-cover, solstice-of-sorrow

06 Solstice 2.4, engine rebuilt about 7k-10k miles ago.

I noticed some oil on the side and bottom of the oil pan. After poking around some more, I found evidence of leaks at:

- Where the turbo oil return line enters the block
- Where the turbo oil return line attaches to the turbo
- At a seal on the turbo housing on the compressor side of the oil feed
- Valve cover gasket, exhaust side. (Inline 4-banger)

When revving the engine in the driveway, I saw a bit of smoke. I then discovered some fresh oil on top of the exhaust manifold - just a few drops - that was burning off. Looks like it was ejected through the valve cover gasket when I revved the engine. The head has oil residue on the exhaust side below the gasket, but not above it. Thus, leaking valve cover gasket.

I checked the oil, and the level is *way* above the full line. The graduated portion of the dipstick is about an inch long (pretty standard). I see oil a good 1/2 - 3/4" above that. Hot, cold, whatever. Yes, I cleaned the stick.

My question is: if the oil change shop overfilled the car, would it cause these things? The car hasn't leaked a drop in several thousand miles, not sure why all of this would start happening at the same time. :(

If not, what else would suddenly cause leaks in 4 different places?

Also, I took a good long look at the return line and, in my opinion, it's not just leaking at the top and running down the line.

I built this motor myself. I was **very** meticulous about proper torque and sequence, gasket installation (not putting RTV on rubber gaskets esp. when the service manual said in Large Friendly Letters to not do so), etc. If the build was a problem, I would expect issues to have appeared much earlier.

Comment: Engine  oil leaks may not always be where the oil appears, engine compartments have several reasons to move oil around with fans being a major contributor.  So clean, run and look again for a single point before looking for a broad spectrum failure.

Comment: @spicetraders thanks for the response. Any suggestions on cleaners / types? I haven't had the greatest luck with the degreaser spray at the car wash. Based on the oil drops that sprayed onto the exhaust manifold, I'm confident that the valve cover gasket, at least, is leaking. I may pull the valve cover and have a look.

Comment: Myself I just use a cheap laundry detergent or dish soap mixed about 50% with water and spray bottled on let set a bit and rinse.